# creating an efficient algorhithm to find all the concurrent timeframes in a list of timeframes

Tags: python, algorithm

I have a list of timeframes and would like to create a map/dictionary that gives me all the timeframes in which an overlap is occuring.

E.g. if my timeframes were `0-1, 0.5-1.5, 1.3-2.3, 1.4-2.4` the desired output would be

```
{
    (0.5,1):2,
    (1.3,1.4):2,
    (1.4,1.5):3,
    (1.5,2.4):2
}
```

My initial approach was to loop over the provided list twice and save each occurence where the time I am comparing with was within the the range of the duration of the timeframe of the starting time. This causes a problem though, e.g. when two times are identical and count each other, resulting in two entries for the particular timeframe instead of just one. Saving each combination I found in a seperate list also feels like a waste of computation power, since this function is going to be called a lot and is running on a microcomputer. Is there a resource-effective solution to this problem?

The number of timeframes is indefinite and I would need about 6 decimal places

Comment: Can you elaborate what overlap means.
From my definition, i dont see how there's 2 overlaps for `(0.5,1)`

Comment: Are your times always given with a single decimal place, or could you have 0.7865487-1.333339 ? How many timeframes is the most you would have?

Comment: @FishballNooodles sorry, the two meant that there are two concurrent timeframes from 0.5 to 1. Do you think it would be less confusing if it said 1 instead?

Comment: @MarkSetchell The number of timeframes is indefinite and I would need about 6 decimal places

Answer (score 0):

Solution (credit@ liberachat ColonelJ)

```
from typing import Optional

def find_overlaps(intervals: list[tuple[float, float]]) -> \
        list[tuple[tuple[float, float], int]]:
    points: list[tuple[float, int]] = sorted(
        [(s, 1) for (s, _) in intervals] + [(e, -1) for (_, e) in intervals],
        key = lambda p: p[0]
    )
    result: list[tuple[tuple[float, float], int]] = []
    overlap: int = 0
    last_point: Optional[float] = None
    for (p, i) in points:
        if last_point is not None and last_point < p:
            if overlap > 1:
                result.append(((last_point, p), overlap))
        last_point = p
        overlap += i
    return result

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(find_overlaps([(0,1),(0.5,1.5),(1.3,2.3),(1.4,2.4)]))
```

Comment: Could you provide some explanation as to WHY this works? Even some comments would be nice. Thanks, and welcome to the site!